# Firebird Database does not recognize unicode/cyrillic letters

Tags: database, encoding, firebird, collation

I really need someone's help with the encoding issue when trying to query Firebird tables.

I am connecting to a firebird database using Firebird Maestro:
[image: Connection string]

The problem is that whenever I include Cyrillic letters in SQL Queries Firebird does not 'understand' them correctly.

For instance, consider a query with some cyrillic letters:

```
SELECT * FROM ROYALTY
WHERE ROYALTY.PRIM = 'Кириллица'
```

It does not return any values even though there is a row that contains 'Кириллица' value in a PRIM row.

However, everything works fine when using only latin letters:

```
SELECT * FROM ROYALTY
WHERE ROYALTY.PRIM = 'Latin letters'
```

Can somebody suggest what to do, please?

Here are screenshots to make my point clear:

[image: Error]

[image]

I've tried connecting to the database with the following charsets with no positive results:

- NONE
- ISO8859_5
- DOS866
- CYRL
- WIN1251
- UNICODE_FSS

**Additional info:**

- Firebird version: 2.5.2
- Firebird Maestro version 7.7.0.1 (Eng)
- I've tried both Russian and English versions of Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the charset you are using for this column and also be sure to use as connection charset, the charset of your system.
try also with Flamerobin or DatabaseWorbench, or may be the Firebird Maestro can help you, it's clearly related to the tool your are using. Firebird itself have no problem using Cyrillic letters 
And for the Charset in your database choose UTF8.

Comment: Thank you, Makowski! I'am totally using Flamerobin now. It works perfectly with cyrillic letters. I've checked the problematic column charsets and there were set to NONE. I was also connection to the database with NONE charset, so it wasn't the issue.

Comment: Makowski, if you know how to work with FireRobin/Firebird, could you also look at another quesiton, please? FireRobin is great, but I still can't create Views with cyrillic letters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797816/firebird-create-a-view-with-cyrillic-letters-in-where-clause

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are not using parameterized queries.  In IBExpert you can put a ":name" semi-colon and the name of your parameter, and it will prompt with the window below.
[image: IBExpert Parameter Test]

In Java/C# .Net use the API to create queries with parameters.  Right now what you are doing is providing non ANSI characters into the SQL string, and that is not saving how you expected.

I see that you are using Firebird Maestro, I'm not sure what that product uses for parameters but it is worth a look in their documentation to see what it is. http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/firebird/maestro/help/10_04_00_query_parameters/  Actually it appears to be the same format a colon and a name for the parameter.

Comment: Thank you, Lopez. This partially answers my question, but does not solve the problem. If I have a complex query I need manually input several queries via parameter form? this is just nuts to me. Is there nothing better than that? Also, I tried to create a view with parameters, but Firebird throws an error: "SQL Error:  invalid request BLR at offset @1 undefined message number. Error Code: -104. Invalid token"

Comment: Hi Zerg.  Yes that is correct.  The SQL definition for Firebird only accepts ANSI characters. If you need to store non ANSI characters you need to provide it through parameters. The closest I have been able to provide UTF8 characters through SQL is through hex literals. See: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-hexbinstrings.html  For example "たまご" is outputted by using the following query. select CAST(CAST(_utf8 x'E3819FE381BEE38194' as VARCHAR(100)) as blob) from rdb$database  I added a link to Maestro's documentation.